# WPF Mouse Smooth movement issue

Tags: wpf, canvas, mouse, mousemove

I try to draw ellipse on a canvas according to the mouse movement.
I use mouse move event and get mouse Point position X and Y ,  and locate the elippse in the new location inside the canvas. All this is working perfect, I get very smooth ellipse movement.

However, if I change the value of the position that i got(see code below) .  i get very bad smoth issue when moving down the mouse. The ellipse jump about the size of the ellipse size.
it heppens only if the value is about the ellipse size;
I guess it is due the old ellipse in the canvas (kind of : the ellipse skip it self).
Here is my code :

```
 private void MainArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point position = e.GetPosition( canvas);

        //position.X -= 15 ;    // this line couse the problem

        Canvas.SetLeft(PlayerEllipse, position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(PlayerEllipse, position.Y);
    }
```

Looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Solved - i found that i need also to build one more MouseMove handler. for the ellipse itself.
becaouse when my mouse is on the ellipse the event related to the ellipse and not to the container MainArea . see below

```
myEllipse.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(myEllipse_MouseMove);



private void myEllipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MainArea_MouseMove(sender, e);
    }
```